# windows server 2012 remote connecting issue from ubuntu(rdesktop)

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi

We are using windows server 2012 and we are connecting server by remote desktop service(RDS) from ubuntu client and windows client.
This servers hosted in VMware ESXi
Now we can able to connect server from windows client but we unable to connect from ubuntu client machines.
I dnt know this is happening from last few days.
Getting below error
"Unable to connect"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZNig.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Update your RD-Client. ASAP.**

A remote code execution vulnerability exists in unpatched versions of CredSSP. An attacker could relay user credentials or execute code on the target server. RDS uses *a lot* of CredSSP.

The windows [security update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018) addresses the vulnerability by correcting how CredSSP validates requests during the authentication process. Additionally, the latest patch for the windows servers disable CredSSP (RD) logins from unpatched (vulnerable) clients.

There is also a GPO to control the beviour of the server when older clients connet (`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation`). But I would *highly* recommend updating your clients.